# Counting HTML string elements using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've got an ajax request that fetches an HTML string, like:

```
<div class="video">...</div><div class="video">...</div>
```

and I want to count the number of "video" div's as soon as I retrieve the HTML from the server. Is there an easy way to do this?

I tried:

```
.done(function(data) { 
        $(data).find('.video').length
```

but it returns 0.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to what is returned, you have all `.video` elements in the root. So one way to get the number of `.video` elements is to use [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method:

```
$(data).filter('.video').length;
```